# C++ AES Decrypt and Nodejs AES Decrypt producing different outputs

Tags: c++, node.js, encryption, aes

I've reimplemented this AES c++ decryption in nodejs.

The "buffer" contains the encrypted content. 
The "decryptKey" contains the key to decrypt the "buffer".
The "expectedOutput" contains the expected output.

In order to bypass the bad decrypt exception thrown by node I had to disable the autoPadding in my crypt object.

**To simplify I added the c++ code and I added tests to three different algorithms (AES-128-ECB, AES-192-ECB, AES-256-ECB). None of the decrypt results match the C++ output.**

**What am I missing?**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var buffer = new Buffer([
    0x5e,0x51,0xa3,0x53,0x9d,0xe7,0xe5,0xd3,
    0xee,0x30,0xbb,0xf8,0x0c,0x72,0x9f,0x80
]);


var decryptKey = new Buffer([
    0x36, 0x46, 0xb4, 0xf6, 
    0x8e, 0x6d, 0xdc, 0xf4, 
    0xb0, 0x31, 0x7e, 0x81, 
    0x6b, 0x5d, 0x96, 0x55
])

/*
After looking to my C++ code I noticed that despite of providing a 32 length key the 128 argument ensures that only the first 16 bytes are used
var decryptKey = new Buffer([
    0x36, 0x46, 0xb4, 0xf6, 
    0x8e, 0x6d, 0xdc, 0xf4, 
    0xb0, 0x31, 0x7e, 0x81, 
    0x6b, 0x5d, 0x96, 0x55, // 16
    0x15, 0x9c, 0x78, 0x54, 
    0x8c, 0xca, 0x3e, 0x39, 
    0x2d, 0x49, 0x75, 0x5d, 
    0xa1, 0x1a, 0xc3, 0xe3  // 32
])*/

var expectedOutput = new Buffer([
    0xc8,0x6c,0x8f,0x2b,0xe8,0x21,0xc4,0x2e,
    0xfb,0x4a,0x8e,0x8b,0xc3,0x94,0x19,0xc2
]);

// aes_context aes_ctx;
function decrypt(data, password, algorithm, padding){
  if (padding === void 0) padding = true;
  algorithm = algorithm || 'aes-128-ecb';

  //aes_setkey_dec( &aes_ctx, digest, 128 );
  var crypt = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,password);
  crypt.setAutoPadding(padding);
  // aes_crypt_ecb( &aes_ctx, AES_DECRYPT, buffer, buffer );
  var res = crypt.update(data, null, 'hex')
  res += crypt.final('hex');

  return new Buffer(res,'hex');
}

// aes_setkey_dec( &aes_ctx, digest, 128 );
var algoList = [
    'aes-128-ecb',
    'aes-192-ecb',
    'aes-256-ecb'
];

for (var i = 0; i<= 1; i++){
    console.log('\n ******* AUTO PADDING: ' + (padding ? 'ON': 'OFF') + ' ********* ');
    var padding = i === 0;
    for (let algo of algoList){
        try {
            var output = decrypt(buffer, decryptKey, algo, padding);
            console.log(algo + ' => ' + output.toString('hex') + ' < ' + (Buffer.compare(expectedOutput, output) === 0 ? 'ok' : 'ko'))
        } catch (err){
            console.log('Failed to perform ' + algo + ' with autopadding ' + (padding ? ' on ': ' off ') + ' due to ' + err.message);
        }
    }
}

/*
 ******* AUTO PADDING: OFF *********
Failed to perform aes-128-ecb with autopadding  on  due to error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
Failed to perform aes-192-ecb with autopadding  on  due to error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
Failed to perform aes-256-ecb with autopadding  on  due to error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

 ******* AUTO PADDING: ON *********
aes-128-ecb => d9817f142f9bca262b67f6a6be570345 < ko
aes-192-ecb => 9181784373bb6060c04c9ba75de26322 < ko
aes-256-ecb => c5945203368de477e5f0dbeedeb2189f < ko
*/
```

Heres the c++ code

```
#include "aes.h"
#include "sha2.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    unsigned char data[16] = { 
        0x5e,0x51,0xa3,0x53,0x9d,0xe7,0xe5,0xd3,0xee,0x30,0xbb,0xf8,0x0c,0x72,0x9f,0x80 
    };

    unsigned char key[32] = {
        0x36, 0x46, 0xb4, 0xf6,
        0x8e, 0x6d, 0xdc, 0xf4,
        0xb0, 0x31, 0x7e, 0x81,
        0x6b, 0x5d, 0x96, 0x55, // 16
        0x15, 0x9c, 0x78, 0x54,
        0x8c, 0xca, 0x3e, 0x39,
        0x2d, 0x49, 0x75, 0x5d,
        0xa1, 0x1a, 0xc3, 0xe3  // 32
    };

    aes_context aes_ctx;
    aes_setkey_dec(&aes_ctx, key, 128);
    aes_crypt_ecb(&aes_ctx, AES_DECRYPT, data, data);

    for (int i = 0; i< sizeof(data); ++i)
        std::cout << std::hex << (int)data[i];

    /* Output => c86c8f2be821c42efb4a8e8bc39419c2*/
}
```

**references:**

- https://tls.mbed.org/discussions/generic/question-about-using-aes
- http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/link/133660agcLyPgFri4s/ - Example of decryption online

---

The solution based in answer below

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
var buffer = new Buffer([
    0x5e,0x51,0xa3,0x53,0x9d,0xe7,0xe5,0xd3,
    0xee,0x30,0xbb,0xf8,0x0c,0x72,0x9f,0x80
]);


var decryptKey = new Buffer([
    0x36, 0x46, 0xb4, 0xf6, 
    0x8e, 0x6d, 0xdc, 0xf4, 
    0xb0, 0x31, 0x7e, 0x81, 
    0x6b, 0x5d, 0x96, 0x55
])

var expectedOutput = new Buffer([
    0xc8,0x6c,0x8f,0x2b,0xe8,0x21,0xc4,0x2e,
    0xfb,0x4a,0x8e,0x8b,0xc3,0x94,0x19,0xc2
]);

// aes_context aes_ctx;
function decrypt(data, password, algorithm, padding){
  if (padding === void 0) padding = true;
  algorithm = algorithm || 'aes-128-ecb';

  //aes_setkey_dec( &aes_ctx, digest, 128 );
  var crypt = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm,password, new Buffer([]));//new Buffer(32).fill(0).byteLength
  crypt.setAutoPadding(padding);
  // aes_crypt_ecb( &aes_ctx, AES_DECRYPT, buffer, buffer );
  var res = crypt.update(data, null,'hex')
  + crypt.final('hex');

  return new Buffer(res,'hex');
}

// aes_setkey_dec( &aes_ctx, digest, 128 );
var output = decrypt(buffer, decryptKey, 'aes-128-ecb', false);
console.log(Buffer.compare(expectedOutput, output) === 0 ? 'ok' : 'ko');
```

Comment: aes_crypt_ecb - At this point huge warning klaxons should be going off!  Do ***NOT*** use ECB ...  unless you are using ECB for this test program and another mode will just add additional complication that is not relevant to your problem (in which case - kudos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *deprecated* [**`crypto.createDecypher()`**](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password_options) ***derives*** the key from the *password* argument:

> The implementation of `crypto.createDecipher()` derives keys using the OpenSSL function `EVP_BytesToKey` with the digest algorithm set to MD5, one iteration, and no salt.

What you want instead is to use a ***raw*** key. For that you should use [**`crypto.createDecipheriv()`**](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options) instead:

```
  var crypt = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm,password,new Buffer([]));
```

(In ECB mode the IV can be empty)

Of course, the key length must then match the requested algorithm (128, 192 or 256 bits). You key is 128 bits, so only aes-128-ecb will work.

Comment: I tried to use createDecipheriv before but I was passing a 16 byte keys filled with 0x00.  After using the empty buffer as suggest and autoPadding off it magically fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need to pass `false` to `setAutoPadding` is that your ciphertext is *not* padded. You haven't included your encryption code that generates the ciphertext, but I can tell from the length of it that it is not padded, because a plaintext of one block size in length, when encrypted using PKCS#7 padding, will produce a ciphertext that is *two* block sizes in length, rather than the single block that you have.

The reason this decrypts with `aes_crypt_ecb` is that it looks like `aes_crypt_ecb` simply performs individual block encryption/decryption, so does *not* do any padding or unpadding. The Javscript code though, if passed `true` to the `setAutoPadding` function, will be expecting padding (probably PKCS#7). Which will of course fail because your encryption has *not* used padding.

Ideally you should modify your encryption code so that it uses proper padding when doing the encryption, as this is much more secure than not using padding. Otherwise you will need to make sure that your call to `setAutoPadding` is passing `false` when doing the decryption, so the Javascript knows there is no padding.

Comment: I just updated my post. The thing is, no matter the algorithm used the expected output is not met.

Comment: On the C++ side you are using the same buffer as both the input and output to the `aes_crypt_ecb` function. This might not be a problem, but seems unusual. Do you get a different result if you use a separate buffer for the output? In the C++ you are again also telling it the key is only 128-bit while your key array is actually 256-bit long.

Comment: Yes, the output is the same even if I separate the output buffer.

Comment: @Lothre1 I have edited my answer with what I now believe is the problem.

Comment: After looking at the c++ code I noticed that the library slices my encryption key to 128 bits. I added a link to a online AES decrypt tool that is able to produce the same output of my c++ program. Maybe this can help.

Comment: That online tool is not using padding, or at least not checking the padding is valid. I added some random characters to the end of the ciphertext and tried decrypting and it succeeded. If it was expecting padding this would have failed as the padding would not be correct.